# MobaXTerm colors are washed out - how to configure the scheme

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty, xterm, linux-terminal

Out of the box, [MobaXTerm](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/open-source-ssh-terminal-client-for-windows-with-tabs-private-key-auth-more)'s rendering of the Midnight Commander screen looks like this (ZOC by comaprison to the right; PuTTY looks similar):

[washed out http://i.snag.gy/hvxxF.jpg](http://i.snag.gy/hvxxF.jpg)

How can I fix this? Is there some environment variable I could set on the server, or some obscure setting in MobaXTerm?

Also, none of the terminal themes seem to do anything. I've picked the light themes and connected to sdf.org but the colors are still those from "dark background".

Answer (score 4):

you can change the color configuration here:
settings -> configuration -> terminal

Then select a color scheme, for example "Bright". You can click in each of the color and change it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The color settings are located in `~/.mc/ini`. Add a color settings, for example

> `[Colors]`
>   `base_color=lightgray,green:normal=green,default:selected=white,gray:marked=yellow,default:markselect=yellow,gray:directory=blue,default:executable=brightgreen,default:link=cyan,default:device=brightmagenta,default:special=lightgray,default:errors=red,default:reverse=green,default:gauge=green,default:input=white,gray:dnormal=green,gray:dfocus=brightgreen,gray:dhotnormal=cyan,gray:dhotfocus=brightcyan,gray:menu=green,default:menuhot=cyan,default:menusel=green,gray:menuhotsel=cyan,default:helpnormal=cyan,default:editnormal=green,default:editbold=blue,default:editmarked=gray,blue:stalelink=red,default`

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the settings of your current saved sessions, to have the bright color scheme. It has more contrast, just like Putty has:

[image: Midnight Commander after setting scheme to bright]
<sup>*Midnight Commander* after setting scheme to bright</sup>

Comment: Please [edit] your answer so it can stand on its own.  The above just reiterates what the OP wants without answering the question, ***"How?"***

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The default colors are quite bright in Mobaxterm.

NB: `Session` is a very overloaded term, but I refer to `User Sessions` in Mobaxterm (and use it interchangeably).

### To only update one session

1. Right-click on the session you want to edit
2. Edit session
3. Choose a tab from the top for me it's WSL
4. Select the `Terminal settings` tab.
5. Click `customize` next to `Terminal colour scheme`
6. Choose a color under `Terminal colors`
   [image]
7. Select a color from the pallete then click `OK`
   [image]
8. Click `OK` again and the rest of the screens.

[image]

Opening a new session of the one you edited should take the changes into account.

Here is the end result for me.

[image]

---

How to update all current sessions and future sessions
-----------------------------------------

First update the defaults

1. Settings -> Configuration
2. Click `Terminal Tab`
3. Click `Customize` Next to `Color scheme`
4. Under `Terminal colors` update the color that looks washed out.
5. Choose the color that needs to be changed
   [image]
6. Select a color from the pallete then click `OK`
   [image]
7. Click `OK` again and the rest of the screens.

[image]

**Now edit each session and ensure that the `Color scheme` is set to `Default`**

[image]